# Maven dependency error after adding x.y.z.BUILD-SNAPSHOT dependency

Tags: java, maven

I am getting the following error from my pom.xml file.

***Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11 from http://repository.primefaces.org was cached 
     in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of prime-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. 
     Original error: Could not transfer artifact opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11 from/to prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org): The 
     operation was cancelled.***

Below is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.farchis</groupId>
  <artifactId>F_Quote</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Farchis Estimator</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id> 
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.springsource.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>SpringSource Maven Central-compatible Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>     
        <version>1.3</version>      
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>     
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- // -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>   
     -->
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- Tomcat 6 need this 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
   <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

     JSR-330 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    --> 
  </dependencies>    
</project>
```

Comment: I would try to either enforce updates of the snapshots or delete at least the mentioned file's folder in my local repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, check whether the jar file opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11 exists in your repository. If yes, remove the opensymphony:ognl folder in your local repository and run maven install again to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this repo :

```
<repository>
    <id>opensymphony</id> 
    <name>opensymphony</name>
    <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

As opensymphony:ognl is now a dead project and 2.6.11 is quite old

You can try one the updated project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

just a suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

Delete the entire .m2 repo and build again. it worked for me.